# Is Any way to call $this of register.phtml file in login.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to merge both the file (login and Registration) in that did not get $this value for registration and page gonna be burst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The both files doesn't load the same block, `$this` refer to the file block.

1. `login.phtml` have as block : `Customer/Block/Form/Login.php`
2. `register.phtml` have as block : `Customer/Block/Form/Register.php`

What you have to do for merging the both files properly is to create a new phtml `login-register.phtml` for exemple then you put this content within:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_login')->setTemplate('customer/form/login.phtml')->toHtml(); //login form

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_register')->setTemplate('customer/form/register.phtml')->toHtml(); //register form
```

the `login-register.phtml` you declare it in your xml module or in `local.xml` to display it.